# Jquery mobile transition slide page content not refresh to original the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have two pages, one is pageone, which slides to orderpage (order form), when order is completed, a "Thank you for your order" displays, user can slide back to pageone, the problem is when the user slides to orderpage again, the blank order form doesn't show, instead the leftover "Thank you..." still there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
include 's_include';
?>
<script    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
THIS IS MAIN PAGE
<a href="#orderpage" data-transition="slide" id="pen_btn">GO TO PAGE TWO</a>
</div> <!-- pageone -->
</div> <!-- ui-content -->
<div data-role="page" id="orderpage">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#order_btn").click(function(){
    $.post("cgi-bin/order.pl", {
        order:"HELLO WORLD IN READY",
    },
    function(data,status){
      document.getElementById('div_comment').innerHTML = data;
    });
  }); //orderpage
}); //ready
</script>
<div id="div_comment">
<textarea name="text_comment" id="text_comment" placeholder="160 chars or less, no # or @" data-role="none" rows=11 cols=20 onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){return false;}" onKeyDown="limitText2(this,160);" onKeyUp="limitText2(this,160);" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
<span id="commenterr" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:90%;"></span>
<br style="line-height:190%;">
<button id="order_btn" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" style="border: #ffffff 1px solid;">Enter your comment</button>
<a href="#pageone" data-transition="slide">
Back
</a>
</div> <!-- ui-content -->
</div> <!-- page id orderpage -->
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add rel="external" like this, but no help:

```
<a href="#orderpage" rel="external" data-transition="slide" id="pen_btn">GO TO PAGE TWO</a>
```

I don't want to use timer.

Wonder if it's possible to have a blank clean order form every time I slideb to orderpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate DIV in orderpage for displaying the results of the post:

```
    <div id="div_comment">           
        <textarea name="text_comment" id="text_comment" placeholder="160 chars or less, no # or @" data-role="none" rows="11" cols="20" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){return false;}" onKeyDown="limitText2(this,160);" onKeyUp="limitText2(this,160);" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
        <span id="commenterr" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:90%;"></span>
        <br style="line-height:190%;" />
        <button id="order_btn" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" style="border: #ffffff 1px solid;">Enter your comment</button>
        <a href="#pageone" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
    </div><!-- div_comment -->

    <div id="formResults">
```

Then on successful POST, hide the comment DIV, populate the results and show the results DIV:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#orderpage", function(){    
    $("#order_btn").click(function() {
        //on POST success: hide DIV#div_comment and  
        //show results in DIV#formResults
        $("#div_comment").hide();
        $("#formResults").html('Thank you...<a href="#pageone" data-transition="slide" >Back</a>').show();          
    }); //orderpage
});
```

Then using the pagecontainer widget's **[beforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow)** event. Every time orderpage is shown, clear all fields, hide the results DIV and show the comment DIV:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    //when orderpage is shown, hide results, show comment and clear fields
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "orderpage"){
        $("#formResults").html('').hide(); 
        $("#div_comment").show();
        $("#text_comment").val('');
        $("#commenterr").text('');
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/75yvnfLk/)**

Comment: Thanks, ezanker, I will try that, but I have feeling there's got to be simpler solutions, ones with a few lines.

Comment: is there something similiar to rel="external" for sliding page?

Comment: @CindyTurlington, if you use external and not the default AJAX loading, you lose the transitions: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

Comment: Ya, I think I might have to do that :(